# Using Orchard.Forms on the front-end with code only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am using code to create a form using Orchard.Forms. This is the code I have:

```
public void Describe(DescribeContext context) {
        Func<IShapeFactory, object> form =
            shape => {

                var f = Shape.Form(
                    Id: "MyLayoutBasicInformation",
                    _BasicInformation: Shape.Fieldset(
                        Title: T("Basic Information"),

                        _FirstName: Shape.TextBox(
                            Id: "FirstName", Name: "First Name",
                            Title: T("First Name"),
                            Description: T("The name for this field")
                            )
                        )
                    );
                return f;
            };
        context.Form("MyLayoutBasicInformation", form);
    }
```

Most of this type of code is used to render fields in the Admin UI. However, I am trying to render this in the front-end and have not been successful.

I tried using `[Shape]` but couldn't figure how to pull this into it. I also tried creating a `.cshtml` file, but I don't know what code to put into it either.

Any examples of how to render this form in the front-end? I know I can use Custom Forms to create a Content Type to render a form on the front-end using the Admin, but I am trying to do this with code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `IFormManager` in your class and use it's `Build` method to build a new form.

```
        private readonly IFormManager _formManager;
        public YourClass(IFormManager formManager)
        {
             _formManager = formManager;
        }
```

and then call `Build` method like this :

```
var shape = _formManager.Build("MyLayoutBasicInformation");
```

Comment: Awesome. I have a follow-up question (maybe more for more points). See [My Question Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372182/how-can-i-insert-the-save-button-using-orchard-forms)

Comment: glad i could help.and thanks for your support.i will need some extra mins to response next question.apologize for this.

Comment: No problem - you are doing me a favor :)