# How can I insert the Save Button using Orchard.Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Follow-up to [my initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369645/using-orchard-forms-on-the-front-end-with-code-only/17371194?noredirect=1#17371194):

If I create a form in code thusly:

```
public void Describe(DescribeContext context) {
    Func<IShapeFactory, object> form =
        shape => {

            var f = Shape.Form(
                Id: "MyLayoutBasicInformation",
                _BasicInformation: Shape.Fieldset(
                    Title: T("Basic Information"),

                    _FirstName: Shape.TextBox(
                        Id: "FirstName", Name: "First Name",
                        Title: T("First Name"),
                        Description: T("The name for this field")
                        )
                    )
                );
            return f;
        };
    context.Form("MyLayoutBasicInformation", form);
}
```

And inject it into the front-end view thusly (as the answer provided):

```
var shape = _formManager.Build("MyLayoutBasicInformation");
```

My display just shows the field First Name. But there is no button to save it to the DB. Any thoughts on how to accomplish that?

**UPDATE:** I am working with my own custom module. I do have a custom theme applied to it. ShapeTracing is giving me alternates to place in the theme - which I don't know that I want to do.

I put the Build code in my controller thusly:

```
[Themed]
    public ActionResult BasicInformation()
    {
        var basicInformation = _formManager.Build("MyLayoutBasicInformation");
        return new ShapeResult(this, basicInformation);
    }
```

Initially, I hard-coded fields with the HTML helpers. So if my controller was MyController, I had a view like this: ~/Views/My/BasicInformation.cshtml. That file still exists in the module but is now overriden by the Build code.

I suspect I have to toy around with that.

**UPDATE:** I managed to to do this in the function to get a button showing, just have to figure out how to wire it up.

```
_NextButton: Shape.Button(
Id: "NextButton", Name: "Next",
Title: T("Next")
    )
```

But this just displays a button with no text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default submit button will not generated for any form built this way. to add submit button to your form change your code as following :

```
public void Describe(DescribeContext context) {
    Func<IShapeFactory, object> form =
        shape => {

            var f = Shape.Form(
                Id: "MyLayoutBasicInformation",
                _BasicInformation: Shape.Fieldset(
                    Title: T("Basic Information"),

                    _FirstName: Shape.TextBox(
                        Id: "FirstName", Name: "First Name",
                        Title: T("First Name"),
                        Description: T("The name for this field")
                        )
                    ),
                    _Submit:Shape.Submit(Value:"Save") 
                );
            return f;
        };
    context.Form("MyLayoutBasicInformation", form);
}
```

Comment: Great, that's getting me along. I will have more questions. I will post a link here when I do. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: FYI, no worries, but I posted another question regarding Orchard Forms. See [QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429967/how-can-i-manually-save-an-orchard-forms-field).