# How can I manually save an Orchard.Forms field?

Tags: orchardcms

With the following code I am able to manually create a field using Orchard.Forms and display it in a view. Here is the code (relevant only):

`MyLayoutForm.cs`:

```
....
public void Describe(DescribeContext context) 
{
    Func<IShapeFactory, object> myInformation =
        shape => {
            var f = Shape.Form(
                Id: "MyBasicInformation",
                    BasicInformation: Shape.Fieldset(
                        Title: T("Basic Information"),
                        FirstName: Shape.TextBox(
                            Id: "FirstName", Name: "First Name",
                            Title: T("First Name"),
                            Description: T("The name for this field"),
            Required: true
                        )
                    )
                );
            return f;
        };
    context.Form("MyBasicInformation", myInformation);
}
....
```

`MyContoller.cs`:

```
....
[Themed]
public ActionResult BasicInformation()
{
    var myBasicInformation = _formManager.Build("MyBasicInformation");
    // MyData below is my View Model
    var myData = new MyData { Form = myBasicInformation };
    return View(myData);
}

[Themed]
[HttpPost, ActionName("BasicInformation")]
public ActionResult BasicInformationPOST(string nextButton, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    _formManager.Validate(new ValidatingContext { FormName = "MyBasicInformation", ModelState = ModelState, ValueProvider = ValueProvider });

    if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("PersonalInformation");
    }

    var myBasicInformation = _formManager.Build("MyBasicInformation");
    _formManager.Bind(myBasicInformation, formCollection);
    // MyData below is my View Model
    var myData = new MyData { Form = myBasicInformation };
    return View(myData);
}
....
```

`MyData.cs` (View Model):

```
public class MyData
{
    public dynamic Form { get; set; }
}
```

`BasicInformation.cshtml`:

```
....
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost())
{
    ....
    @Display(Model.Form.BasicInformation.FirstName)
    <input type="submit" name="nextButton" value="Next" />
    ....
}
....
```

As of right now the First Name textbox displays properly on my view. I am using a "Next" button to go to the next view (that will be another question later). Validation will fire (I left out the validation parts) if I click "Next" and the textbox is empty. If I fill in the textbox and click "Next" it takes me to the next view (PersonalInformation.cshtml). Clicking "Back" on the second view obviously shows a blank First Name textbox since I haven't figured out how to do that yet.

I've basically patched together code using the Projections/Rules/CustomForms modules to get this far. However, I have tried examples there and elsewhere to save the data (actually, to persist it maybe using Session, but again that's another question on how to do that if at all possible - I know some of the caveats therein). Additionally, the code in those modules I listed above are adding actions to the specific modules in the Admin screens (e.g., Projections), so that code isn't helpful (plus I can't totally figure out what's going on).

So, how can I go about saving, for example, "FirstName"?

I created a Record and a simple migration. Since I am just wanting to store non-content data I did not create a driver or handler. But I don't know that this is the right way to do it AND I am not sure what code to put in my controller.

Any examples are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: so what is your exact question?saving first name in session or creating non content data?if 2nd one is the case then check my previous answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426612/orchard-data-insert-delete-for-non-content-item or not i will post an answer regarding session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in comment if you need to store a non content data in database then follow my answer provided in the comment, but it is much more simpler to store data in session.try following to access and store data in session:

```
 private readonly IWorkContextAccessor _workContextAccessor;



[Themed]
[HttpPost, ActionName("BasicInformation")]
public ActionResult BasicInformationPOST(string nextButton, FormCollection formCollection)
{
 .
 .
 .

if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var HttpContext = _workContextAccessor.GetContext().HttpContext; 

    var basicInfo = new BasicInformation();

    TryUpdateModel(basicInfo);         

    HttpContext.Session["BasicInfo"] = basicInfo;

    return RedirectToAction("PersonalInformation");
}

.
.
.
return View(myData);
}
```

you can access your personal info anywhere later on with `HttpContext.Session["BasicInfo"]`.one other thing , don't forget call `Session.Abandon()` after you finished registering user.do it so :

```
//all user information is gathered and stored in the `database` so let's end user session

   HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
```

**EDIT**

mark your Classes (which you have planed to sore in session) with `Serializable` attribute , you can read why you have to do so [here](http://kbalertz.com/312112/Session-Saved-Session-State.aspx).

Comment: Won't be back for a couple of hours. Yes, I want to temporarily store in session (or is there a better way - Serialize won't work for me?) then pass it to the second view. At the end of the "wizard" I then want to store the data. I mentioned the session thing as a second question i would ask - I just simply want to store the form field that was created as a first step, then figure out how to do a "wizard" type thing (which will require flushing the content if the user doesn't hit a final "Confirm" button. Sorry for the length. I'll be back on in a few hours.

Comment: the session is must appropriate one for you.it will store your wizard's step(s) and carry theme out to last step.and if user leave the registration form without finishing it , data will be flushed when the user session expires.one other thing i forgot to say is that mark your Classes (which you have planed to sore in session) as `Serializable`

Comment: Great! So let's say I string along a wizard, I can then store "PersonalInformation" as `HttpContext.Session["PersonalInfo"]` and then pull them both out in a Confirm page? And finally in my Submit on the Confirm action I can take all of that info (on as many wizard steps as I have stored in Session) and store it as non-content data as you show in your other post? FYI, at most I have 9 steps in the wizard, the confirm page acting as one step.

Comment: Silly question, but does the user closing the browser or navigating away count as flushing the data if the user doesn't finish? I.e., is it going to happen right away, or will it linger?

Comment: absolutely not .but you can set `Session.Timeout` to a short time so that it finish in an earlier time after user leave the form.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In terms of my comment about stringing along a wizard, is what I mentioned accurate (store each step in wizard in a separate session - or should I add it to the first session? and whether I can pull all of that on the confirm page and submit as non-content data?). Again, thanks!

Comment: what you mean with "separate session" and "first session"? session is a dictionary of `string => Object` in which you can store any object and associate it with a unique key.to store your wizard steps in this dictionary just use this pattern `Session["StepName"] = ObjectContainingStepInfo`. in case of first step : `Session["BasicInfo"] = basicInformation`.